# thread functoin can't read char from buffer allocated on heap from

Tags: c++, multithreading, winapi, memory-management, byte

I have a thread function, creating some struct called data slot and pass it to another function that needs to fill the data slot data.
after filling the data slot with data I can print the data in the same filling function, but when returning to the thread function, it can't print it, saying "invalid characters in string". that's the  thread function code:

```
unsigned __stdcall some_class::WriteBufferToFile(void * args) { 
    queue<wstring> * Q = (queue<wstring> *)args;
    myfile->open(ThisObj->DebugOutputPath, ios::out | ios::app | ios::binary);
    DataSlot * d = new DataSlot;
    ThisObj->ConvertCharactersToDataSlot(*Q, d);

    for (unsigned i = 0; i < d->Size; i++) { // printing doesn't works here !
        cout << d->RawData[i];
        *myfile << d->RawData[i];
    } 
    myfile->close();
    delete d;
    return 0;
    }
```

that's the ConvertCharactersToDataSlot code:

```
void some_class::ConvertCharactersToDataSlot(queue<wstring> ToConvert, DataSlot * d) {
    wstring CombineStr = L"";
    while (!ToConvert.empty()) {
        CombineStr += ToConvert.front();
        ToConvert.pop();
    }
    unsigned size = wcslen(CombineStr.c_str()) * sizeof(CombineStr[0]);
    d->Size = size;
    d->RawData = new BYTE[size];
    d->RawData = reinterpret_cast<BYTE *>(&CombineStr[0]);
    for (unsigned i = 0; i < d->Size; i++) { // printing works here !
        cout << d->RawData[i];
    }
}
```

I really need to solve this, I can't understand why this is happening, according to the os memory management methods this makes no sense that the memory is unreadable. maybe it's some bug in my code, any ideas guys?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are overwriting pointer to allocated buffer with a pointer to the buffer or local string object that goes out of scope and leaves `d->RawData` with a dangling pointer:

```
d->RawData = new BYTE[size];
d->RawData = reinterpret_cast<BYTE *>(&CombineStr[0]);
```

You should probably *copy* data to allocated buffer instead:

```
::memcpy(d->RawData, CombineStr.data(), size);
```

You also need to make sure you free buffer allocated for `d->RawData`.